# compering times (H:i:s) , ignoring seconds if zero

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

so i work with a system where i have to do lots of time comparing and by that i mean `H:i:s`

the problem is sometimes there are `00` for seconds and sometimes it isnt and since times are given to me as string
comparing to similar times with and without second zeros will fail

here we have 2 similar times but my if will fail for missing seconds in one

```
$db_time = '11:20';
$given_time = '11:20:00' ; 

if($db_time == $given_time )
{
     echo "same time";
}
else 
{
    echo "different time";
}
```

right now i use something like

```
if( in_array( $given_time , [$db_time , "$db_time:00"] )  )
{
     echo "same time";
}
else 
{
    echo "different time";
}
```

which is not ideal !! specially since i dont know which one is missing the zeros

i do use with `carbon` , i prefer if i can solve this by using carbon

Comment: Why don't you create Date objects and compare them?

Comment: Time of day or duration? Most solutions you'll find on the internet will assume the former and they'll break is H is greater than 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$db_time = '11:20';
$given_time = '11:20:00';

if(Carbon::parse($db_time)->eq($given_time)) {
    echo "same time";
} else {
    echo "different time";
}
```

Comment: i get `different time`

Comment: This exact same code gives "same time" on https://try-carbon.herokuapp.com/ Are you sure of the values of your variables?

Comment: you're right , this is very odd  ... using  `DateTime`  works tho ! i ran the same times on `Carbon` and `DateTime`  both work on`try-carbon` but on my local only `DateTime` works

Comment: Try to update Carbon, you might be on an old version.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Date objects and compare them.

```php
$db_time    = '11:20';
$given_time = '11:20:00';

echo isSameTime($db_time, $given_time) ? 'same' : 'different';

function isSameTime(string $time1, string $time2): bool
{
    return new DateTime($time1) == new DateTime($time2);
}
```

echoes

```
same
```